# Add Curl page animation on CALayer?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, calayer, transition

Is that possible on iphone or ipad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this implementation](http://oleb.net/blog/2010/06/app-store-safe-page-curl-animations/). It is freely available.

Comment: Hey, i already tried that. it works great but i dont like the look of it. i was able to create a curl to left and right by rotating a UIView but i need to add it to a CALayer and want to know if its possible? Thamks

Comment: confirmed your answer as it the best solution i found. but it seems you can not add the build in curl to the layer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`PageViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH4-SW3). It is a standard apple controller that automatically implements the page curl between 2 views for you.

It's only available from iOS 5 onwards though.

Comment: Thanks I know about PageViewController. but it's for iOS 5 and later :)

Comment: Ah yeh, forgot to mention that!